# Uniform convergence with respect to some metric using pointwise convergence

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose (X, d) is a metric space. Let $(f_n(x), n=1,2,..)$ and $f(x)$ be functions from $[a,b]$ to $X$ such that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} d(f_n(x), f(x))=0$ for every $x \in [a,b]$. Moreover, $f$ is continuous with respect to $d$ and for every $x_1, x_2, x_3$ such that $a \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq b$ the following holds $d(f(x_1), f(x_2)) \leq d(f(x_1), f(x_3))$ and $d(f_n(x_1), f_n(x_2)) \leq d(f_n(x_1), f_n(x_3))$. I need to show that $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f(x)$ in $[a,b]$.

I started writing $d := d(f_n(x), f(x)) \leq d(f_n(x), f_n(b)) + d(f_n(b), f(b)) + d(f(b), f(x))$. Hence $d \leq  d(f_n(a), f_n(b)) + d(f_n(b), f(b)) + d(f(b), f(a)) $. On the other hand for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $n$ large enough such that $d(f_n(a), f(a)) < \epsilon$ and $d(f_n(b), f(b)) < \epsilon$. Therefore, $d<2*\epsilon + 2*d(f(b), f(a))$. But I think this is to strict estimate, then I tried using continuity of $f$ and for every $x$ took a neighborhood of $x$, but still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$d(f(x),f(y)) \leq \varepsilon$$

for all $|x-y|<\delta$. Choose a partition $a=x_0<\ldots<x_m=b$ such that $\max_j |x_j-x_{j-1}|<\delta$. By the estimate you suggested, we have

$$d=d(f_n(x),f(x)) \leq 2\varepsilon + d(f(x_j),f(x_{j-1})) \leq 3\varepsilon$$

for all $x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]$ and $n\geq N(j)$ sufficiently large. Hence,

$$\sup_{x \in [a,b]} d(f_n(x),f(x)) \leq 3\varepsilon$$

for all $n \geq \max\{N(j);j=1,\ldots,m\}$.

Comment: thank you, I used this. But then I get $\sup_{x \in [a,b]} d(f_n(x), f(x)) < \sum sup_{x \in [x_i,x_(i+1)]} d(f_n(x), f(x)) < n* 3 * \epsilon$, which does not go to 0 in general, when $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @Meryl How do you arrive at the factor $n$ at the right-hand side? $$\sup_{x \in [a,b]} d(f_n(x),f(x)) = \max_{j=1,\ldots,m} \sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]} d(f_n(x),f(x)) \leq 3\varepsilon$$

Comment: You both seem to be masters at latex.

Comment: yeeees, now I understood my mistake. thank you. :)

Comment: @Meryl You are welcome. If the answer satisfies you, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.